# swift 2: Unable to save in parse updated value of nested pfobject array property

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, ios9

I am using iOS 9 with Swift 2 and Parse.
I have a PF object like the one below, created in advance and pulled down from parse.

```js
 {
   "history" = [
     {
       "completed": false,
       "date": "December 1, 2015",
       "id": "dlxIHMO4lgDecember 1, 201507:15:06"
     }
   ],
   "user" = "john doe"
}
```

I am trying to update the `completed` property to true and save it.

```
var daily = PFObject(className: "Drops")
let query = PFQuery(className: "Drops")
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil || object == nil {
      print("The getFirstObject request failed.")
    } else {
      print("Successfully retrieved the object")
      daily = object!
      (daily["history"][0]).setValue(true, forKey: "completed")

      daily.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          if (success) {
            print("completion saved in parse")
          } else {
            print("completion could not be saved in parse")
          }
      }
    }
}
```

While debugging, the property value looks updated but in parse it shows the old value of false.

I am not sure what I am missing!
I've also tried using `daily.saveEventually()` without success.

Comment: Your code isn't editing, it's creating new. And is it just an array of dictionaries?

Comment: It is an object with 2 properties. "user" is a string property and "history" is an array of objects.

Comment: Ok.nyour new code is comparing a user object to a string so I expect your query to never return results. Why aren't you using pointers and relationships? It would really help to know the exact definition of the object and how you know which one needs to be updated. When you debug do you have the object to update, if so saving should be fine.

Comment: The object does update, when I view it before parse save kicks in. `daily["history"][0]["completed"]` is set to `true`. But, doesn't seem to get through to parse. I am new to swift2 and parse. So, I am finding my way around.